# How do I initialize an empty array inside a java script object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const cart = {
  // I am initializing an empty array
  contents: "[]",
  addItem(item) {
    // I am adding an element to the array
    contents.push(item);
  }
};

cart.addItem("laptop");
console.log("The cart contains:", cart.contents);
```

Comment: well, first you need an empty array... rather than a string.

Comment: Anything inside quotes is a string, not an array.

Comment: @Steve Please verify the answer

Answer (score -2):

This will be the correct format for the same

```js
const cart = {
    // I am initializing an empty array
    contents: [],
};

function addItem(item) {
    // I am adding an element to the array
    cart.contents.push(item);
}
addItem("laptop");
console.log("The cart contains:", cart.contents);
```

**OR**

```js
const cart = {
    // I am initializing an empty array
    contents: [],
    addItem(item) {
        // I am adding an element to the array
        this.contents.push(item);
    }
};

cart.addItem("laptop");
console.log("The cart contains:", cart.contents);
```